# echo json_encode has no response from server, but regular echo does?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, cross-domain

I am trying to do a test request from my localhost, to a dev site I have just to test out some code. I am trying to make a very simple `fetch` request that simply just echos a response back in the form of `json`. This is cross site request and am disabling cors. The issues is, when I try to echo a response with `echo json_encode` the response says: 
`failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier`.
However, if I simply fire a regular `echo 'a';` before the `echo json_encode` both responses now show up in the network tab. I am using Chrome. Here some code:

```
fetch('https://example.com/test.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    mode: "no-cors",
    body:JSON.stringify({
        test:'1'
    })
})
.then(r => r.json())
.then(function(r){
    console.log(r)
})
```

In php I simply have, which returns nothing.

```
if(empty($_POST)){
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
}
echo json_encode(['200'=>'Got it']);
```

If I do:

```
echo 'x';
echo json_encode(['200'=>'Got it']);
```

My response looks like: (which the browser detects as proper json)

```
x{'200':'Got it'}
```

Do you have any ideas? I have tried putting any/all of these in my php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Content-type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
json_last_error_msg();
```

Any ideas? thank you.

Comment: `x{'200':'Got it'}` is not a proper json
a proper json object it should be 
`{ "x" : {'200':'Got it'} }`

Comment: sorry, but did you fully read? the "x" is the first echo'd "x" followed by the json being echod. in the network tab, it just puts the next to each other

Comment: yes I did read otherwise i wouldn't have replied.
When you try and fetch `x{'200':'Got it'}` as a json content type will throw an error since the json is not valid.

Comment: we are getting off topic, the response from the JS fetch request handler has little/nothing to do with what is showing up in the network tab. when i said the browser detects it as valid json, its because i can literally click the arrow on it and it will expand the json object. https://i.imgur.com/8dzX2rV.png

Comment: What if you `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` just use this code. The result?

Answer (score 0):

You can echo out either an array or an object:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->message = 'gotit';
$obj->code = 200;
echo json_encode($obj); // prints {"message":"gotit","code":200}

$arr = Array('200' => 'gotit');
echo json_encode($arr); // prints {"200":"gotit"}
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this works

```
<?php
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo json_encode(['200'=>'Got it']);
exit();
```